# I need to quickly remove a set of classes from an arbitrary string of html

Tags: php, html, regex

The HTML is run through a purifier first (tinyMCE+Wordpress), so it should match somewhat standard forms.  all script and style tags are stripped, and all data inside tags is html_encoded, so there are no extraneous symbols to worry about.

I know the general stance on parsing html with regular expressions is "don't", but in this specific example, the problem seems less like parsing, and more like simple string processing...  am I missing some unseen level of complexity?

As far as I can break it down, it seems like the pattern in question can be broken down into logical components:

1. `/<[a-zA-Z][^>]+` - matches the start of any html tag and any mix of tags and attributes within, but not the end bracket
2. `(?i:class)=\"` - the start of a class attribute, case-insensitive
3. `(?:` - start a non-capturing sub-pattern
4. `(?: *[a-zA-Z_][\w-]* +)*` - any number of class names (or none), but if they exist, there must be whitespace before the capture
5. `( *`.implode('|', $classes).`*)` - the set of classes to capture, preg_quoted
6. `(?: +[a-zA-Z_][\w-]* *)*` - any number of class names (or none), but if they exist, there must be whitespace after the capture
7. `)+` - close the non-capturing subpattern and loop it in case multiple matching classes are in one attribute
8. `\"(?: [^>]*)>/` - the end of the class attribute, and everything to the end of the html tag

making the final regex:

```
$pattern = "/<[a-zA-Z][^>]+ (?i:class)=\"(?:(?: *[a-zA-Z_][\w-]* +)*( *".implode('|', $classes)." *)(?: +[a-zA-Z_][\w-]* *)*)+\"(?: [^>]*)>/";
```

I haven't tried running this yet, because I know if it works, I'll be heavily tempted to use it, but running this through a `preg_replace` seems like it should do the job, except for one minor issue. I believe it will leave extraneous whitespace around the capture area.  This isn't a significant issue, but it might be nice to avoid, if anyone knows how.

It should also be noted that this is not a mission-critical process, and if my capture occasionally fails to remove the classes, no one dies.

so, in essence... can someone explain what makes this a bad idea in this case?

Comment: Complexity is: the start of `class` attribute can only be matched with `\bclass`, class names can include a lot of things - but maybe you *know what you are doing*, `preg_quote` works if you have word characters at the boundaries, and if not? What if `>` is not entitized (`class="dd>"`)?

Comment: @stribizhev - edge cases like `>` in the class name would be filtered and removed by the sanitizer, before getting to this code, and there is a pretty high expectation that the code received will have been generated by a logical script, to boot.  however, I'm not sure I'm following the issue with the class attribute... elaborate?

@Robert - I'm concerned about speed.  This modification needs to run on every page load (i know, but i'm limited in many ways), and parsing the html into a DOM object is a lot more memory/cpu intensive than the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, is that the list of classnames you want to remove from a given html?

what i mean to say, is what is the given list of classnames you want to remove. Can you give an example of the typical html, what it is, and what you want to change it to.
Example:

Before

```
<div class="someClass">
  <i class="dontchange doChange"></i>
  <a class="hello john"></a>
</div>
```

Change to

```
<div>
  <i class="dontchange"></i>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I intend to populate the list of classnames on a case by case basis, but they will be a set of string literals that have been escaped for use in regular expressions.  the class names to remove will be functionally equivalent to (str1|str2|str3).  your example is accurate, although I don't need to go so far as to remove empty class attributes... in the worst case, I could clean those up with a str_replace, after the fact

Answer (score -1):

This will replace all the classes in all the html.

```
myHtml.replace(/class\=\"[^\"]*\"/g,'');
```

Is this what you are looking for? Or something more specific?

Comment: or if there is a very unusual edgecase where class="" doesn't exist inside a tag you could do this: myHtml.replace(/(<[^>]*)class\=\"[^\"]*\"/g,'$1');

Comment: nope, trying to replace only classes that appear in a given list, not looking to match all classes

Comment: Whay is the given list?

Comment: it will be a list of preg_escaped strings, that may change from use to use... in any regex, they should be functionally equivalent to `(str1|str2|str3)`.